# How to hide a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I face problem that my div.hide is not working, because it just shows and whenever I click back link "reply" it's does not hide.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('click','a.btnGG',function(){
    var va=$(this).data('comment_id');
    $("#parent_id").val(va);
    $("#formReply").attr("va",$("#formReply").attr("va") + va);
    $(".formms").hide();
    $(this).after('<div class="formms">'+$(".gg").html()+'</div>');

    $("#hides").onclick(function (){
        $(".gg").css("display","block");
    });
</script>
```

tpl

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="hides" class="btnGG" > reply</a>
<div class="gg"  style="display:none;">
    <form action="/commenter/web/index.php" id="formReply"  method="Post" >
        <input type = "hidden" name ="m" value = "{$m}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="{$data.comment_id}"/>
        <input type = "hidden" name="post_id" value="{$req.post_id}" />
        <!--  <input type = "hidden" name="user_id" value="{$req.user_id}" /> -->
        <input type = "hidden" name ="c" value = "do_add_comment_reply" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value=""/>

        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Please leave a reply of the comment "></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_reply"  name="btn_reply" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reply">

    </form>
</div>
```

I'm beginner programmer.

Comment: there are a variety of possibilities why this goes wrong, it may be because you haven't wrapped your code in a document ready function, it may be because you haven't closed the bracket of the click function, it may be because `onclick` is a js function and you're mixing it with jQuery, simply use `click` instead and see if they fix your problem!

Comment: First of all, read the comment above. Next, what does "val(va)" mean? It doesn't exist. Neither does the attar "va" on your next line. Please give some more information about your goal and what needs to be done because it's not very clear...

Comment: I can't see any element in the code snippet, which had a class `formms` at the time you're trying to hide it.

Comment: it is always good to share a JSFiddle with the problem, inviting more quick responses!

Comment: There are so many issues with your code, few are mentioned above, other than that, you're injecting elements with `id`, that results in multiple elements with same id, which invalidates your `HTML`. You're *trying to* add an event handler inside another event handler which will eventually create so many event handlers in an element.. Please try to fix these and update the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are doing with your code. If you simply want to display div or hide clicking on reply button, there's a complete code (TPL file):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>




<a href="javascript:;" id="hides" class="btnGG" > reply</a>
<div class="gg"  style="display:none;">
    <form action="/commenter/web/index.php" id="formReply"  method="Post" >
        <input type = "hidden" name ="m" value = "{$m}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="{$data.comment_id}"/>
        <input type = "hidden" name="post_id" value="{$req.post_id}" />
        <!--  <input type = "hidden" name="user_id" value="{$req.user_id}" /> -->
        <input type = "hidden" name ="c" value = "do_add_comment_reply" />
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value=""/>

        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Please leave a reply of the comment "></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_reply"  name="btn_reply" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reply">

    </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click','a.btnGG',function() {
        $(".gg").toggle();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="javascript;" id="hides" class="btnGG" > reply</a>
<div class="gg"  style="display:none;">
  // Code
 </div>
```

Change it to something like

```
<a href="#" id="hides" class="btnGG" > reply</a>
<div class="gg" id="testid"  style="display:none;">
  // Code
 </div>
```

and use script like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hides").onclick(function(){
      $("#testid").toggle("show");
   });
});
```